# angular2-template-loader produces incorrect output, why?

Tags: angular, webpack

Please, observe the following TypeScript file:

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    templateUrl: './app/app.component.html'
})
export class AppComponent {
}
```

And it works fine before I use angular2-template-loader. When I am trying to use the latter and run webpack it fails with the following message:

```
    polyfills.js     283 kB       1  [emitted]  polyfills
       vendor.js    3.32 MB       2  [emitted]  vendor
     main.js.map    17.2 kB       0  [emitted]  main
polyfills.js.map     353 kB       1  [emitted]  polyfills
   vendor.js.map    3.94 MB       2  [emitted]  vendor
      index.html  607 bytes          [emitted]
    + 912 hidden modules

ERROR in ./src/client/app/app.component.ts
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve 'file' or 'directory' ./app/app.component.html in C:\Users\markk\IdeaProjects\QuestionarySample2\src\client\app
 @ ./src/client/app/app.component.ts 18:22-57

...
Child html-webpack-plugin for "index.html":
        + 1 hidden modules

C:\Users\markk\IdeaProjects\QuestionarySample2>
```

(there are more errors like that for other components, I replaced them with an ellipsis)

The loader converts the aforementioned source into:

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    template: require('./app/app.component.html')
})
export class AppComponent {
}
```

And now it fails.

As I understand, the reason is that **require** works off the current directory, whereas the **templateUrl** is relative to the root. So, './app/app.component.html' is correct when taken relative to the root, but wrong when relative to the current location.

It is worth noting, that I do not use **require** anywhere in the source code, only the ES6 **import** statement, which is also relative to the current location. It is only the Angular2 **templateUrl** and **styleUrls** that are relative to the root.

Anyway, I must be doing something wrong, because nobody seems to have my problem. But what am I doing wrong?

The file name is **src/client/app/app.component.ts**. The source code directory structure is:

```
C:.
│   .gitignore
│   karma.conf.js
│   package.json
│   tsconfig.json
│   tslint.json
│   typings.json
│   webpack.config.js
│           
├───config
│       karma-test-shim.js
│       karma.conf.js
│       webpack.common.js
│       webpack.dev.js
│       webpack.prod.js
│       webpack.scratch.js
│       webpack.test.js
│       
└───src
    ├───client
    │   │   global.css
    │   │   index.html
    │   │   main.ts
    │   │   polyfills.ts
    │   │   tsconfig.json
    │   │   vendor.ts
    │   │   
    │   └───app
    │       │   app.component.html
    │       │   app.component.ts
    │       │   app.module.ts
    │       │   app.routing.ts
    │       │   settings.component.ts
    │       │   signout.component.ts
    │       │   
    │       ├───assets
    │       │       ...
    │       │       
    │       ├───questionnaire
    │       │       ...
    │       │       
    │       └───shared
    │               ...
    │               
    └───server
            api.ts
            main.ts
            tsconfig.json
```

The webpack configuration is:

**webpack.config.js**

```
module.exports = require('./config/webpack.dev.js');
```

**./config/webpack.dev.js**

```
var webpackMerge = require('webpack-merge');
var ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
var commonConfig = require('./webpack.common.js');
const path = require('path');

module.exports = webpackMerge(commonConfig, {
    // devtool: 'cheap-module-eval-source-map',
    devtool: 'source-map',

    output: {
        publicPath: `http://localhost:${commonConfig.port}/`,
        filename: '[name].js',
        sourceMapFilename: '[name].js.map',
        chunkFilename: '[id].chunk.js'
    },

    plugins: [
        new ExtractTextPlugin('[name].css')
    ],

    devServer: {
        inline: true,
        hot: true,
        progress: true,
        port: commonConfig.port,
        proxy: {
            '/api*': {
                target: `http://localhost:${commonConfig.port - 1}`
            }
        },
        historyApiFallback: true,
        watchOptions: {
            aggregateTimeout: 300,
            poll: 1000
        }
    }
});
```

**./config/webpack.common.js**

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
var ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    port: process.env.PORT || 3000,

    entry: {
        polyfills: './src/client/polyfills',
        vendor: './src/client/vendor',
        main: './src/client/main'
    },

    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, '../dist/client'),
    },

    resolve: {
        extensions: ['', '.js', '.ts']
    },

    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.ts$/,
                loaders: ['ts', 'angular2-template-loader']
            },
            {
                test: /\.html$/,
                // loader: 'html'
                loader: 'raw'
            },
            {
                test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|svg|woff|woff2|ttf|eot|ico)$/,
                loader: 'file?name=assets/[name].[hash].[ext]'
            },
            // {
            //     test: /\.css$/,
            //     exclude: path.join(__dirname, '../src/client/app'),
            //     loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract('style', 'css?sourceMap')
            // },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                // exclude: path.join(__dirname, '../src/client/app'),
                loader: 'raw'
            }
        ]
    },

    plugins: [
        new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
            name: ['main', 'vendor', 'polyfills']
        }),

        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: 'src/client/index.html'
        })
    ]
};
```

I have opened an issue, but I think it is just something I misunderstand - https://github.com/TheLarkInn/angular2-template-loader/issues/20

**EDIT 1**

Guys, before suggesting changing

```
templateUrl: './app/app.component.html'
```

to

```
templateUrl: './app.component.html'
```

Please, read the Angular2 documentation. Specifically https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/architecture.html and look for the text **app/hero-list.component.ts (metadata)**. There is only one occurrence of it:
[image]

Notice the file **app/hero-list.component.ts** references the template **app/hero-list.component.html**. The reference is relative to the **root**, not the current location.

Plus, I have already mentioned that the code works fine without the loader and with the './app/app.component.html' path.

Could be a breaking change in one of the Angular2 RCs, I do not know. But this is the current state of affairs.

Comment: just use    templateUrl: 'app.component.html'

Comment: Why would it work? Angular2 documentation is unambiguous about it - the url is relative to the root. But I checked it anyway and, as expected, it does  not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### It has nothing to do with the angular2-template-loader the error is coming from webpack while it's failing to locate the file you required

### What does angular2-template-loader?

The angular2-template-loader searches for templateUrl and styleUrls declarations inside of the Angular 2 Component metadata and replaces the paths with the corresponding require statement.

The generated require statements will be handled by the given loader for .html and .js files.

If you go to your build file and search for your AppComponent you will find that angular2-template-loader has converted `templateUrl: "path"` to
`templateUrl: require("path")`

### This

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    templateUrl: './app/app.component.html'
})
```

### Should be

```
@Component({
    moduleId: module.id, //not for webpack
    selector: 'app-root',
    templateUrl: './app.component.html'
})
```

> setting moduleId: module.id in the @Component decorator is the key here. If you don't have that then Angular 2 will be looking for your files at the root level.
>
> Webpack developers have an alternative to moduleId.
>   They can load templates and styles at runtime by adding ./ at the beginning of the template and styles / styleUrls properties that reference *component-relative URLS.

[Question on Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5043867/pardeep-jain)

[Angular Docs](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-relative-paths.html)

```
─app
    │   app.component.html--->same folder
    │   app.component.ts---->same folder
    │   app.module.ts
    │   app.routing.ts
    │   settings.component.ts
    │   signout.component.ts
```

When you ask for `templateUrl: './app/app.component.html'` it's looking for app folder in current directory which does not exist and you get the error.

Comment: I guess that architecture is built on SystemJS and you are using webpack that's a big difference.

Comment: It is working without the loader just fine. I understand that `require` uses the current location, but Angular2's templateUrl is resolved relative to the root regardless of the loader, because this is done by Angular2 itself. My code does not use SystemJS, I use webpack and yet it works fine without this specific loader simply because I do not use **require**. But I have already explained it in the post. I want to know how to use the loader without changing my code, because if I do it will become coupled to that particular loader. Right now it is not and I would like to keep it this way.

Comment: The only explanation I have is before you were going to the absolute path and now you are using angular2-template-loader which convert it to require and then webpack want to build it inside bundle but it can not resolve it. I guess you were not bundling Html in your build before and now it does?

Comment: I have never used absolute paths. The original code is referring to **'./app/app.component.html'**. I was not bundling html in my code before, that is correct. This is the first time I am trying to do it and it just does not work.

Comment: As told earlier with experience webpack is trying to find a path which does not exist and the right also is to use only file name from the same folder not the folder name. It's also more logical to give only file name when you are in the same folder. I know you want to follow angular docs but lots of stuff been changing there and they don't have a architect for webpack version.

Comment: **templateUrl** in Angular2 is expected to be relative to the root. Period. It is not negotiable. I did not invent it. This is how Angular2 works. angular2-template-loader rewrites it using the **require** pattern. Hence it should be part of the logic of the loader to adjust the path to be relative to the current location, not the root. Are you suggesting to write incorrect Angular2 code and rely on angular2-template-loader to make it right?

Comment: Please let me know if you find the right way to use it in will also follow it 

Comment: I was wrong about "not negotiable". It is and https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/component-styles.html mentions it at the end of the page. A cookbook chapter is dedicated to it - https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-relative-paths.html. Angular CLI sets it up like this. I do not use Angular CLI and hence I am exposed to the problem. The fix is trivial - adding an explicit moduleId = module.Id to the @Component.

Comment: Glad that you understand the difference. I think I can add some more info to answer. Please accept the answer if you feel it is useful.

Comment: I will definitely accept once you added the **moduleId: module.Id** to the @Component. Emphasizing its importance and providing a link to the relevant Angular 2 documentation would be helpful as well. Not to me, but to others facing the same issue.

Comment: just a heads up: both links found in this answer are now broken